# checking and waiting until a selenideelement attribute contains a specific string

Tags: java, selenide

How to check and wait until a specific attribute of an selenideelement contains a string through Selenide api. Say if I want to wait until "href" attribute contains the word "Test"

Answer (score 0):

```
element.shouldHave(attribute("href", "Test"));
```

> In most cases, you don't need #waitUntil or #waitWhile methods because
>   all should- methods wait too. You need to use #waitUntil or #waitWhile
>   methods only if you need another timeout.

For instance:

```
element.waitUntil(attribute("href", "Test"), 10000, 1000);
```

- where 10000 is timeoutMilliseconds and 1000 is pollingIntervalMilliseconds

Reference:
[SelenideElement](https://selenide.org/javadoc/current/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html)

Answer (score -1):

Selenide element = $("your_locator") ;
element.waitUntil(have(cssValue("href", "test"), your_time) ;